# Sphinx Documentation, numbered figure references

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I'm trying to get numbered figures to work on my Sphinx documentation project using latexpdf output. I installed the Sphinx numfig.py extension found here https://bitbucket.org/arjones6/sphinx-numfig

However, whenever I use the :num: tag that is supposed to provide a cross reference with the figure's number I instead get the following

rst

```
.. _fig_logo:


.. figure:: logo.*

        Example of a figure

Reference to logo :num:`figure #fig_logo`
```

Generates output:

Reference to logo figure **??**

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's happening it you replace the 'logo.*' to the filename without wildcard?

Comment: It still produces a figure ??

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I thought not having a figure was the issue.  Now I see it's not having the reference (:num:) is the problem.  Also at my side...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that if you have an underscore in your label name (like in `fig_logo`) sphinx replaces this with a minus (`-`, this makes sense as latex sometimes behaves strange in  cases whit underscores), while the reference still uses the underscore.
For that reason latex can not find the label referenced.

This is the resulting tex code generated by sphinx:

```
\includegraphics{logo.png}
\caption{Example of a figure}\label{index:fig-logo}\end{figure}

Reference to logo \hyperref[index:fig_logo]{figure  \ref*{index:fig_logo}}
```

(Note the difference between `fig-logo` as label and `fig_logo` as reference.)

If you replace the underscore by a minus for instance

```
.. _fig-logo:


.. figure:: logo.png

        Example of a figure

Reference to logo :num:`figure #fig-logo`
```

the tex code looks like this:

```
\includegraphics{pandas_bar.png}
\caption{Example of a figure}\label{index:fig-logo}\end{figure}

Reference to logo \hyperref[index:fig-logo]{figure  \ref*{index:fig-logo}}
```

and in the pdf generated this is resolved to

**Reference to logo figure 1**

### Update

If you don't want to change all the labels you can update `numfig`: it should be sufficient to add the line

```
target = target.replace('_', '-')
```

just before line [27](https://bitbucket.org/arjones6/sphinx-numfig/src/b2345f7d9fabefbd103c31cc0c4c26c68b29ac6a/numfig.py?at=default#cl-27) in your copy of the extension.

I opened an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/arjones6/sphinx-numfig/issue/9/references-are-not-resolved-if-underscore) on bitbucket.

Comment: Is there a possible fix to the extension? there are a lot of labels that would need changing.

Comment: Does this imply that Sphinx's rst->latex conversion treats the '-' and '_' the same all the time?

Comment: I don't know. I was looking through the source code of sphinx, but I didn't found any replace call for the moment. I'm not sure if this is done in sphinx or in the underlying `docutils`. However in general latex is sensitive to underscores, so I would try to avoid undersores.

Comment: The underscore-to-hyphen substitution is done in the `docutils.nodes.make_id()` function.